# Problem getting typescript class to work with CSR

Tags: client-side-rendering, typescript

I am trying to write a TypeScript/React class that will only get instantiated once and is accessible globally. The reason for this is a SharePoint CSR script. I load this script for New/Edit/Display forms and in my list, I have different content types. One of those content types is a child of another content type and I have written a react component that renders a few buttons in the NewForm of the parent content type so I can create child items from inside the NewForm. So far so good, but my CSR script gets instantiated every time a Form opens, meaning it will get instantiated for both my parent content type and child content type.

This is where my problem lies. I need to remove a few items from a drop down in the child content type's NewForm based on a value of another drop down in the parent NewForm. But because my script gets instantiated for both forms, the values I set in my validation class aren't in sync.

Here is my code:

```
class MyCsrScript{
   private validator: Validator;
   constructor(){
      this.validator = new Validator();
   }

   protected getTemplates(): SPClientTemplates.TemplateOverrides {
      let templates: SPClientTemplates.TemplateOverrides = {};

      templates.Fields = {
         "ParentDropDown": {
            NewForm: this.attachValidator,
            EditForm: this.attachValidator
      }
   }

   protected postRender(ctx: SPClientTemplates.RenderContext) {
      let fCtx = ctx as SPClientTemplates.RenderContext_FieldInForm;
      let field = fCtx.ListSchema.Field[0];
      if(field.Name === "ChildDropDown"){
         this.validator.setChildDD($("#" + field.Name + "_" + field.Id + "_\\$DropDownChoice"));    
         this.validator.validate();            
      }
   }

   private attachValidator(ctx: SPClientTemplates.RenderContext_FieldInForm) {
      let formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
      formCtx.registerInitCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function(){
         let initialValue = getInitialValue(); //this will have a value for EditForm.aspx. For NewForm.aspx, it will be ""
         <ParentDropDown initialvalue = {initialValue} onChange={this.parentDDChange.bind(this)} />
         validator.setParentDropDownValue(initialValue);
      }
   }

   private parentDDChange(lookupValue: string) {
      this.validator.setParentDropDownValue(lookupValue);
      this.validator.validate();
   }
}

export class Validator{
   constructor(){  }

   public setChildDD(dropdown: JQuery){
      //Set child drop down
   }

   public setParentDropDownValue(value: string){
      //set value of parent drop down
   }

   public validate(){
      //remove options from child drop down depending on parent drop down value here...
   }
}
```

Basically, validator will get instantiated once when attachValidator is fired and once when postRender is fired. The second instance won't have the parent drop down's value. I already tried implementing a singleton pattern, but I got the same results here. So does anybody know how to solve this?

To clarify, I have added a little diagram:

[image]